# How to set up and serve a fail whale-like server overload page?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, lamp

We have a fairly large member site set up on AWS using a medium high-CPU server. Most of the time it runs at very low capacity (~3%), but once a week we send out a newsletter to our members with opportunities. In the minutes after the newsletter the server load shoots up (sometimes to over 100%) with members trying to access the site.

In the long term, we will be restructuring the system, but for now, I'd like to add an overflow server that will serve a 'try back in a few minutes' page to users while this is occurring.

I haven't been able to find any good how-tos on setting up routing for this type of thing. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) along with [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) instead?

That would allow you to match the number of servers to your actual usage.  Most of the week, you would not be paying for 97% unused capacity, and during the newsletter periods, you will have enough capacity for everyone to log on and buy something from you.

Comment: This does not seem like a solution to the above problem.

Comment: @williamtell: Care to elaborate?  It is in fact a solution, one which the OP accepted. ELB can distribute incoming web requests across any number of web servers, and auto scaling can help automate the process.  To be sure I would script adding one server to the ELB configuration just before newsletter launch.  Auto Scaling will automatically add additional capacity as needed if my initial estimate of an extra server was insufficient for a given week.

Comment: Yes, but the question above is about how to put an error page in place. You are offering a longer term solution, but the question is how do you set up an error page for when there is latency or a crash due to heavy traffic volume?

Comment: @williamtell: Stack Overflow isn't just about literally answering a question literally, but also about pointing out a better solution than the OP was after.  Given that he accepted the answer, I think I have succeeded in doing that.  My solution is actually more effective (provides a copy of the website) while being less work (just spin up a new server from a snapshot, no need to create any new configuration with an error page).

Answer (score 0):

There is a post on the Amazon Web Services blog that explains how to do this.  It puts failover web page on S3, which is easy to maintain and cheap.

[Create a Backup Website Using Route 53 DNS Failover and S3 Website Hosting](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/create-a-backup-website-using-route-53-dns-failover-and-s3-website-hosting/)